# Fix timezone issue with database in Rails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My Rails app is hosted on Heroku with a Postgress database. For a certain model I'm asking the user to chose a day and a time, which I combine to a date before saving the model:

```
  def create_timestamp
    self.date = day.to_datetime + time.seconds_since_midnight.seconds
  end
```

When I chose for instance today @ 20:50:00 and store it in the database, my record looks like this:

```
<Report id: 1, account_id: 1, date: "2016-11-05 20:50:00", description: "test", created_at: "2016-11-05 19:50:57", updated_at: "2016-11-05 19:50:57", deleted_at: nil, user_id: 1, report_category_id: 2, time: "2000-01-01 20:50:00", day: "2016-11-05">
```

As you might notice, the created_at date is different, because it's in a different timezone. While the created_at is stored in UTC +0000, my custom date, which uses local timezone is CET +0100.

So when I type in console: `Report.find(1).date`, it returns 2016-11-05 21:50:00 +0100.

How can I store the correct date in the initial set, or make the database return the correct timezone when querying?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing currently is basically this:

```
>> date = Date.new(2016, 11, 6)
=> Sun, 06 Nov 2016
>> time = Time.new(2000, 1, 1, 20, 50, 0)
=> 2000-01-01 20:50:00 +0100
>> date.to_datetime + time.seconds_since_midnight.seconds
=> Sun, 06 Nov 2016 20:50:00 +0000
```

`to_datetime` converts the time-zone-less `Date` into a `DateTime` representing *midnight UTC* on that date, and then you add 20 hours and 50 minutes.

Instead of midnight UTC, you want *midnight in your local time zone* as your starting point. So you could do this, for example:

```
>> date.in_time_zone + time.seconds_since_midnight.seconds
=> Sun, 06 Nov 2016 20:50:00 CET +01:00
```

Rails should then be smart enough to convert it to UTC when storing in the database and back to CET when retrieving from the database.

To be clear about the difference, compare:

```
>> date
=> Sun, 06 Nov 2016
>> date.to_datetime
=> Sun, 06 Nov 2016 00:00:00 +0000
>> date.in_time_zone
=> Sun, 06 Nov 2016 00:00:00 CET +01:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
Time.zone.now
# or 
Time.current
```

Which will return the time in time zone

Comment: I'm trying to process user input, which could be different from the current time. Thanks for your reply though.